# [Questions about a proof in the prelim of paper "Lattice-Based Zero-Knowledge Proofs and Applications"]

Tags: lattice-crypto

May I ask that in section 2.7 challenge space in the paper [Lattice-Based Zero-Knowledge Proofs and Applications:
Shorter, Simpler, and More General](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/284.pdf)

[image]

What is rot(c), why does rot(c) $\in Z^{d*d}$, and why |rot(u)|<sub>2</sub> <= |u|<sub>2</sub> ? 
And may I also ask that what is $S_{k}^{\delta}$
Also, I am new to lattice crypto, I would truly appreciate it if someone pointed out some resources of learning the math behind ring theory that is essential to read these papers?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$rot(c)$ is the matrix defined by the rotation matrix depending on the number field you are working in, in the paper the number field is $K = \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^d+1)$ which has a ring of integers $R = \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^d+1)$ and $R_q= \mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^d+1)$.

Let  $\left\{X^i | i\in \left\{ 0,\ldots ,d-1 \right\}\right\}$ be a basis of $R_q$.

the $rot$ is defined to be the rotation matrix that send $a = \sum_{i=0}^{d-1}{a_iX^i} \in R_q$ to
$$\begin{bmatrix}
|&|&|&|\\
a*1 & a*X &\cdots& a*X^{d-1}\\
|&|&|&|
\end{bmatrix}$$
such that $a*x^i  = \begin{bmatrix} 
a_{0+i\mod d}\\
a_{1+i\mod d}\\
\vdots\\
a_{d+i\mod d}\\
\end{bmatrix}$

#### Example

if $d=4$  then

for an element $a = a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+a_3X^3$ of $R_q$ $$rot(a)= \begin{bmatrix} 
a_0  & -a_3 & -a_2 & -a_1\\
a_1  & a_0  & -a_3 & -a_2 \\
a_2  & a_1  & a_0  & -a_3\\
a_3  & a_2  & a_1  & a_0\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

now it is clear why the $|rot(u)|_2 \leq |u|2$ from the definitions in page 11  and the fact that $\Vert u\Vert ^2  = \Vert rot(u) u \Vert $ which is smaller than $\Vert rot(u)\Vert \Vert u \Vert $ thus the result.
for the last question  you can find a good library in https://thelatticeclub.com/

I suggest to start with Basic  by Basic Lattice Cryptography: Encryption and Fiat-Shamir Signatures Vadim Lyubashevsky

also check this [A Tutorial Introduction to Lattice-based Cryptography and Homomorphic Encryption](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.08125)

I hope that I helped you.

Answer (score 2):

My [previous answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/107797/103719) gives intuition on what $\mathbf{rot}(a)$ is, which you might find useful.